# How can I cleanly start and stop VirtualBox VMs using launchd?

Tags: launchd, catalina, shutdown

Does anyone have a working macOS 10.15, Catalina, shell script for cleanly starting/stopping VirtualBox VMs using launchd?

It seems macOS 10.15 has broken the standard solutions you find when searching for this. I suspect a proper solution would have some instruction to run this shutdown command first, before other shutdown scripts activate.

I have a launchd job that runs VirtualBox via a shell script I've written. The "stop" part of my script fails uses this `trap SIGTERM` function:

```
function shutdown()
{
  while (true) ;
  do
    found=$( ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $VBOX_PID | grep -c $VM ); 
    if [ "$found" == '0' ]
    then
        break
    fi
    VBoxManage list runningvms
    VBoxManage controlvm my_vm savestate
    sleep 5
  done
}
```

The whole thing works fine when I try load/unload:

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/home.vbox.plist
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/home.vbox.plist
```

I can repeat the above and the VM will appear, then stop saving its state, then reappear where it left off and so on. However, when I actually shut down my computer, the VM is killed after the exit timeout and starts fresh on startup (no saved state). I used the StandardErrorPath/StandardOutPath to save the output to a file and discovered that the `VBoxManage` commands fail to run during system shutdown. Instead of running they repeatedly log:

```
Killed: 9
```

Adding some logging, I also noticed that it seems that other parts of the OS have already stopped (e.g. the `whoami` command returns the numeric UID instead of the user name. I suspect that the reason I cannot perform a clean shutdown is because VBoxManage requires some part of OS X that is already disabled at this stage (which explains why it works fine when I do load/unload without actually shutting down, but fails during an actual shutdown).

UPDATE: I've set up password-less login using a host-only network interface and tried to have my shutdown function run `ssh root@10.5.5.1 shutdown -H -P now` to initiate the shutdown from the guest side. I discovered however that you can't even launch the ssh client during shutdown! Instead I got the error `No user exists for uid 502` which indicates that some directory service has shut down causing problems in creation of processes...